# What is the recommended approach to handle blue/green deployments with Commerce on Azure

Tags: sitecore-commerce, azure, deployment, scaling

Is there a recommended/standard approach to handling blue/green deployments for Sitecore Commerce services?

Our Sitecore app services are hosted on Azure and we are able to do zero-downtime deployments, only if commerce is unchanged. If commerce has to be updated, then there needs to be some downtime for the one of the Sitecore CD environments.

Is there a way to temporarily switch to using the Authoring environment while upgrading Shops?

If not, what/how many services need to be duplicated?

Comment: you can create patch config to temporarily switch to authoring environment.
You can also load balance shops service and update one at a time.

Comment: Thanks @VipinBanka. The latter sounds like a better bet. Would that just involve load balancing the CommerceShops app service and nothing else?

Comment: PS if you want to put that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily switching your CD environments to point to authoring service is possible by patch config.

Instead of switching you can load balance your commerce shops service and update services one by one.

With OOTB service roles load balancing make sense to CommerceShops only.